# Connected Smooth Projective curve $C$ is rational if unirational

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-schemes

Following question: Why and how to see that a connected, smooth, projective curve $C$ (so a so a $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme) is rational if it is unirational.

Remark: unirational means that there exist a dense morphism $\phi: \mathbb{P}^n \to C$

Especially that would mean that every unirational normal curve have a rational point.

Remark #2: This question arises from the answer given https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319483/extend-group-action-of-mathbba1-g-to-projective-line

but it seems to me that my question above about the step in the given answer would be too low for a further MO-thread.

Comment: Your mention a curve several times but also say "$2$-dimensional, proper $k$-scheme" in your post while clarifying your definition of a curve. Is this a typo? If not, could you clarify your meaning?

Comment: of course a typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is called Lüroth's theorem; see, e.g., [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108766/116766). For an elementary proof, you can look at Theorem 1.3 in [this book by Ojanguren](http://sma.epfl.ch/~ojangure/WL.pdf).

For more canonical references, you can look at Jacobson's [*Basic Algebra II*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1009787), p. 522, or Hartshorne's [*Algebraic Geometry*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), Ex. IV.2.5.5.

Below is a version of Ojanguren's argument that I wrote down for a course taught by Mircea Mustaţă. See Lecture 1, Theorem 2.1 in [his notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mmustata/lectures_rationality.html), or Theorem 1.6 in my [LiveTeXed notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~takumim/Rationality.pdf) from the course.

*Proof.*
  We show that if $k \subseteq K \subseteq k(t)$ is a sequence of field
  extensions such that $\operatorname{trdeg}_k K = 1$ and $t$ is transcendental over $k$, then $K \simeq k(X)$ for a transcendental element $X$ over $k$. Since
  $\operatorname{trdeg}_k K = 1$, it is enough to find some $a \in K$ such that
  $K = k(a)$.

First, the second extension $K \subseteq k(t)$ must be algebraic, so
  $t$ is algebraic over $K$. Let
  $$
    f(X) = X^n + a_1X^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n \in K[X]
  $$
  be the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K$. Since $t$ is
  transcendental over $k$, we cannot have all $a_i \in k$, and so there is some
  $i$ such that $a_i \in K \smallsetminus k$. We will show that in this case, $K
  = k(a_i)$. We know that the $a_i \in K \subseteq k(t)$,
  and so we may write
  $$
    a_i = \frac{u(t)}{v(t)},
  $$
  where $u,v \in k[t]$ are relatively prime, and where at least one of them of
  positive degree by the assumption that $a_i \notin k$. Now consider the following polynomial:
  $$
    F(X) = u(X) - a_iv(X) \in k(a_i)[X] \subseteq K[X].
  $$
  Since $F(t) = 0$, we have that $f(X) \mid F(X)$ in $K[X]$ by minimality of
  $f(X)$, and so
  \begin{equation}
    u(X) - a_iv(X) = f(X)g(X).\tag{1}\label{eq:0105star}
  \end{equation}
  where $g \in K[X]$. We then claim the following:

*Claim.* $g \in K$.

Showing the Claim would conclude the proof, for then we have a sequence of
  extensions
  $$
    k \hookrightarrow k(a_i) \hookrightarrow K \hookrightarrow k(t)
  $$
  where $t$ is the root of a degree $n$ polynomial in $k(a_i)[X]$, hence
  $[k(t) : K] \ge n = [k(t) : k(a_i)]$, which implies $K = k(a_i)$.

To prove the Claim, the first step is to get rid of all denominators: by
  multiplying \eqref{eq:0105star} by $v(t)$ and the product of all denominators in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, we
  get a relation
  $$
    c(t)\bigl(u(X)v(t) - v(X)u(t)\bigr) = f_1(t,X)g_1(t,X),
  $$
  where $c(t) \in k[t]$ is nonzero and $f_1(t,X),g_1(t,X) \in k[t,X]$ are obtained from $f$ resp. $g$ by
  multiplication by an element in $k[t]$. Note that $k[t,X]$ is a UFD, hence every prime factor of $c(t)$ divides either $f_1(t,X)$ or $g_1(t,X)$.
  Thus, we can get rid of $c(t)$ by successively dividing by prime factors of $c(t)$
  to get a relation
  \begin{equation}
    u(X)v(t) - v(X)u(t) = f_2(t,X)g_2(t,X),\tag{2}\label{eq:0105rel3}
  \end{equation}
  where now $f_2(t,X),g_2(t,X) \in k[t,X]$ are obtained from $f,g$ by
  multiplication by a nonzero element in $k(t)$. The trick is now to look at the
  degrees in $t$ on both sides. First,
  $$
    \deg_t\bigl(u(X)v(t) - v(X)u(t)\bigr) \le \max\bigl\{\deg u(t),\deg
    v(t)\bigr\}.
  $$
  Letting $f_2(t,X) = \gamma_0(t)X^n + \cdots + \gamma_n(t)$, we see that
  $$
    \frac{\gamma_i(t)}{\gamma_0(t)} = a_i(t) = \frac{u(t)}{v(t)},
  $$
  where we recall that $u(t),v(t)$ were relatively prime. This implies that in fact,
  $$
    \deg_t\bigl(f_2(t,X)\bigr) \ge \max\bigl\{\deg u(t),\deg v(t)\bigr\}.
  $$
  By looking at degrees in $t$ on both sides of the relation
  \eqref{eq:0105rel3}, we have that $\deg_t(g_2(t,X)) = 0$, hence $g_2 \in k[X]$.

Now we show that $g_2 \in k$. For sake of contradiction, suppose that
  $g_2 \notin k$. Then, there is a root $\gamma \in \overline{k}$ such that
  $g_2(\gamma) = 0$, which implies that $u(\gamma)v(t) = v(\gamma)u(t)$ by \eqref{eq:0105rel3}. But
  since $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are relatively prime, and are not both constants, we
  must have $u(\gamma) = 0 = v(\gamma)$. This contradicts that $u,v$ are
  relatively prime, and so $g_2 \in k$.
  Finally, since $g \in K[X]$ and $g = g_2 \cdot (\text{element of
  $k(t)$})$, we have that $g \in K$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: hi, thank you a lot for the detailed explanation. Essentially Lüroth theorem proves $\mathbb{P}^1 /G \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ taking into account famous category equivalence between the categories of smooth projective algebraic curves  and function fields of trdeg $1$ showing that both have isomorphic function fields, right? the aspect that I unfortunately can't find in your answer ...please correct me if I have ovenseen this point ...is  that the thread primary not refers to the statement from my previous MO question about $\mathbb{A}^1 /G \cong \mathbb{A}^1$

Comment: but to two intermediate results occured in the answer concerning unirational curves in general. namely why normal unirational curve has a rational point (or the more stronger result that which appropriate extra conditions it is already ration. I'm not sure how this can be also answered with Lüroth.

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz I am a bit confused, since I thought you were asking about why unirational implies rational for curves in your original question, so that is the question that I answered. In any case, a unirational curve always has rational points: Suppose $f\colon \mathbf{P}^1 \dashrightarrow C$ is a dominant rational map to a complete curve. Since $\mathbf{P}^1$ is regular, $f$ is in fact a morphism. Now $\mathbf{P}^1$ has multiple $k$-rational points, and these map to $k$-rational points on $C$.

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz I also notice you said "two intermediate results". Do you have other questions in addition to why unirational implies rational for curves, and why unirational curves have rational points? I apologize for missing them, if you have already mentioned them on this page!

Comment: no sorry I have just overseen that Lüroth's statement for intermediate fields from wiki - namely  that every intermedadiate extension between $K$ and $K(X)$ is generated by single element - has a geometric version: and this is exactly that unirational implies rational so  what I was asking for. this I exactly what I meant by "intermediate result".

Comment: Two points stay unclear. You used in your last comments follwing argument: If we start with dominant rational $f\colon \mathbf{P}^1 \dashrightarrow C$. Why the fact that $\mathbf{P}^1$ is regular imply that $f$ is already a morphism; so everywhere defined?

Comment: And secondly  I'm not sure if I have understood correctly that "unirational implies rational" is exactly the geometric version of Lüroth's classical formulation for intermediate fields. Let me summarize it: the existence of dominant rational morphism $f\colon \mathbf{P}^1 \dashrightarrow C$ gives corresponding field extension $K(C) \subset K(\mathbf{P}^1)= K(t)$ and algebraic Lüroth says just that $K(C)$ is also generated by a single element.

Comment: This imply that $K(C) =K(x)$ so $C$ is rational since it has a function field isomorphic to the projective line and this is exactly the Definition for rational curve. but here occure following problem: since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is regular $f$ is by your Argument above a morphism between smooth proj alg curves with isomorphic function fields. Does the category equivalence I mentioned above already imply that $C$ is already isomorphic to projective line? this conclusion  seems to strong for me.

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz For the claim that a rational map from a regular curve to a projective variety can be extended to a morphism, see [Hartshorne, Prop. I.6.8]. The more general version for maps to complete schemes follows from the valuative criterion for properness; see \[[Görtz–Wedhorn](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-8348-9722-0), Thm. 12.60\]. For your second question, yes, any regular complete curve birational to $\mathbf{P}^1$ is in fact isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^1$. This follows from [Hartshorne, Cor. I.6.12], for example.